# Entity Framework Core: Loop reference on getting rows

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these 2 tables:

```
public class Book
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Library Library { get; set; }
}

public class Library
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Well, when I run this code:

```
_context.Books.Include(b => b.Library).ToList();
```

I want to get only the books with their library and the entity **Library** with the Books property as null. But I get this property with every books of the libraries, then when I want to update one book always throw the Exception:

> The instance of entity type 'Book' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

Is there any way to get all the books with the Library property **Books** as null value?

Comment: add the ef generated sql please

Comment: "_then when I want to update one book_" - please share the code for that update operation.

Comment: @atiyar _context.Books.Update(book);

Comment: Please don't share code in the comment section. Edit your post and add the complete operation, including where `book` is coming from (e.g. a method parameter).

Comment: isnt this a circular reference?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier yes, I just want to avoid this circular reference, i have read that EF Core do this by default when you use .Include()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get all the books with the Library property Books
> as null value?

If that is your *only* requirement, then use projection like -

```cs
var books = _context.Books
        .Select(p => new Book
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Library = new Library { Id = p.Library.Id }
        }).ToList();
```

If you have lots of properties in your models, you might want to consider using [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to do the projection for you, like -

```cs
var books = Mapper.ProjectTo<BookDTO>(_context.Books).ToList();
```

You will need to define DTO models with *only* the properties you need, like -

```cs
public class BookDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LibraryDTO Library { get; set; }
}

public class LibraryDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and to define the mappings for them -

```cs
CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>();
CreateMap<Library, LibraryDTO>();
```